# Почему NaN не равняется NaN?

Tags: node.js, javascript

```
console.log( null == null, undefined == undefined, NaN == NaN ); // true, true, false
```

Почему?

Comment: не рАвняется

потому что js - язык со странностями.

Comment: Значение x == NaN и x === NaN всегда false для любого x, даже если x=NaN.

Причем в любом яп.

Comment: И да, значение NaN не равно никакому другому числу, и даже самому NaN.

Так гласят мануалы :)

Comment: >потому что js - язык со странностями

@Etki справедливости ради, дело тут не в странностях языыка, а в математике

Comment: Не рАвняется, исправил :) А вот про любой язык.. Сейчас в php проверил и в as3 (выбор пал из-за наличия онлайн компиляторов под рукой) и там NaN равен NaN...

Comment: >Сейчас в php проверил и в as3 ( выбор пал из-за наличия онлайн компиляторов под рукой ) и там NaN равен NaN..

[взгляните][0]

[0]:http://ideone.com/SwTs8y

Comment: Был не прав по поводу NaN в других языках :) Спасибо всем.

Comment: @vas, а еще у JS и AS один и тот же стандарт ECMAScript, поэтому они мало различаются в поведениях на базовом уровне.

Comment: @DreamChild, тогда и undefined не должен быть равен undefined. Это бы имело смысл, если бы в языке не было null, но он есть.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Попробуем взглянуть на проблему с точки зрения математики. Как известно,  NaN - это типичный результат для действий вроде деления бесконечности на бесконечность или ноля на ноль и прочих операций, результат которых с математической точки зрения не определен или не имеет смысла. 
Например, из математики известно, что логарифм отрицательного числа не определен. То есть следующая операция будет иметь результат NaN:

```
Math.log(-5) // NaN
```

При этом если вы попробуете выполнить такую операцию: 0/0 то ее результатом тоже будет NaN. В таком случае напрашивается вывод, что Math.log(-5) и 0/0 равны (в обоих случаях мы получим NaN). Очевидно, что это не так. Поэтому Принято допущение, что NaN не равен даже самому себе.

(более того, будь NaN равен самому себе, то помощью нехитрых преобразований можно было бы прийти к выводу, что 2 == 1)

Иными словами, NaN - это не какое-то конкретное значение, а просто некая достаточно удобная абстракция, под которой могут скрываться самые разные значения, совершенно не равные друг другу.

У этого парадокса есть любопытное следствие: функцию IsNAN легко реализовать таким образом:

```
return arg !== arg;
```

Comment: @DreamChild, Спасибо!

Comment: А вот результаты IEEE 754

    1 / 0 = inf
    -1 / 0 = -inf
    1 / -inf = -0.000000
    -inf / -0 = inf
    1 / inf = 0.000000
    inf / inf = -nan
    -inf / -inf = -nan
    0 / 0 = -nan
    -0 / 0 = -nan
    0 / -0 = -nan
    -(-nan) = nan
    -nan = -nan
    sqrt(-1) = -nan
    -sqrt(-1) = nan
    -nan / -nan = -nan
    nan / -nan = nan
    -nan / nan = -nan
    nan / nan = -nan
    
на Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz (printf ("%f\n", ...); gcc 4.8.2).

--

Интересно, что появляются `-nan` и `-0`

Comment: @avp: Судя по всему, багофича glibc: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3772835/276994

Answer (score 6):

Mozilla [пишут про NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) так:

**Описание**

NaN – это свойство глобального объекта.

Начальное значение `NaN` это Not-A-Number — то же, что у `Number.NaN`. В современных браузерах `NaN` это неизменяемое, только для чтения свойство. Даже в случаях когда это не так, не переопределяйте его.

Использование NaN в программах довольно редко. Это значение возвращается в случаях, когда не удаётся вычислить ф-ии объекта `Math` (`Math.sqrt(-1)`) или терпит неудачу преобразование строки в число (`parseInt("blabla")`).

**Сравнение с NaN**

Операторы равенства (`==` и `===`) нельзя использовать для сравнения значения с NaN. Вместо этого используйте метод `Number.isNaN()` или `isNaN()`.

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

> Сейчас в php проверил и в as3 ( выбор
> пал из-за наличия онлайн компиляторов
> под рукой ) и там NaN равен NaN

Да ну :) уверен что он там равняется ?

```
if (NAN == NAN) {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

или даже так

```
var_dump(NAN == NAN); // boolean false
```

В любом **ЯП** NAN == NAN => false